# NServiceBus with Azure Service Bus, always checking existence of namespace and queue

Tags: azure, nservicebus, azureservicebus

I am using NServiceBus, with Azure Service Bus as the transport. Every time I send a message, I see the following in the logs:

```
Checking existence cache for '...'
Checking namespace for existance of the queue '...'
Determined that the queue '...' exists
Queue '...' already exists, skipping creation
```

Despite being noisy in the logs (I can filter these messages out, but that's besides the point), I worry about the overhead of this checking every time. How can I configure NServiceBus to expect these namespaces and queues to exists and stop checking with every message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry, it isn't checking remotely all the time (the logs point at checking the cached information)

https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AzureServiceBus/blob/master/src/Transport/Creation/Resources/AzureServiceBusQueueCreator.cs#L115

Feel free to filter the log entries out of your log file if they bother you.